# Setting up Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, gnome3, settings

How can I:

- disable left hot corner in Gnome 3?
- make the favorites bar (or dock or what's it called?) to be shown always?
- is there any way to show (open) the list of applications like I can do in Mac by pressing F4?

I want to do that with **no gnome extensions I have to download.** Only manually even if it requires editing or some programming or by dconf-editor.

Comment: As a general rule, post one question at a time. I don't know about 3 (in linux almost anything is possible if you're skilled enough) but 1 and 2 could be done via extensions. Since you don't want to use extensions the only option is to run your own version of gnome-shell. There are no files to edit as it comes as a binary so you could [try this guide](http://worldofgnome.org/how-to-extract-shell-from-gresource/) to extract the files, edit the relevant ones and run your own shell.

Comment: @don_crissti, so how come the extensions can do 1 and 2 and I myself can't? Extenstions are simply text files. Text files!

Comment: I didn't say you can't; you definitely can but not via editing the shell `js` text files as everything is now a binary... in the past yes, that used to be an option but not anymore. You can either write your own extensions (it's unclear whether you don't want to use extensions at all or just don't want to download them) or run your custom gnome-shell.